# javascript - how to import typescript type to js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've two files: one is typescript and one is javascript.

`typescript` file `types.ts`

```
import { MyUser, Notification } from './models';

export type Theme = 'v1' | 'dark';

export type Action =
  | { type: 'LOGIN', payload: MyUser }
  | { type: 'LOGOUT' }

  | { type: 'NOTIFICATIONS_ADD', payload: Notification }
  | { type: 'NOTIFICATIONS_CLEAR' }
  | { type: 'NOTIFICATION_DISMISS', payload: number }

  | { type: 'THEME', payload: Theme }
;

export type Dispatch = (action: Action) => void;

export type Option = { value: string, display: string };
```

`javascript`:

```
const dispatch = require('../../src/types.ts');

// const dispatch = require('Dispatch').load({
//   path: '../../src/types.ts'
// });
```

I would like to use `Dispatch` in my `js` file. Tried both ways (with commented line) but getting an error saying `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

How do I use `typescript` `export type` in javascript file ?

Comment: You can't import the original Typescript file in javascript, but you can import the transpilated version of the Typescript in your javascript.

Comment: You can't, `import` is not a keyword in javascript. You have to "translate" your TypeScript to JavaScript before include it.